# Vue 2 - child components are not rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I can't wrap my head around this issue at the moment. Main parent component isn't rendering the child components. No error is thrown when the page is loaded.

I have this code so far:

HTML:

```
<td class="countries-visible-filter">

    <visible-filters>
        <show-query-filter :selected ="true" query="all" name="All | "></show-query-filter>
        <show-query-filter query="true" name="Visible | "></show-query-filter>
        <show-query-filter query="false" name="Hidden"></show-query-filter>
    </visible-filters>
```

Parent component:

```
Vue.component('visible-filters', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <span v-for="filter in queryFilters"
                :class="{'text-muted' : !filter.isSelected}"
                @mouseenter="changeClassMouseenter($event)"
                @mouseout="changeClassMouseout($event)"
                @click="countryTest(filter)"
            >
                {{filter.name}}
            </span>
        </div>
    `,

    methods: {
        countryTest(filter) {

            this.filters.forEach(singleFilter => {
                console.log(singleFilter);
            });

            Event.$emit('country-filter', filter);
        }
    },

    created() {
        console.log(this);
        this.queryFilters = this.$children;
    },

    data() {
        return {
            queryFilters: []
        }
    }
});
```

Child component:

```
Vue.component('show-query-filter', {
    template: `
        <div><slot></slot></div>
    `,

    props: {
        query: '',
        selected: false,
        name: {required: true}
    },

    mounted() {
        this.isSelected = this.selected;
    },

    methods: {

        changeClassMouseenter(event) {
            if(!this.selected)
                event.target.classList.remove('text-muted')
        },

        changeClassMouseout(event) {
            if(!this.selected)
                event.target.classList.add('text-muted')
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            isSelected: false
        }
    }

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using `show-query-filter` as a [slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots), not as a child of `visible-filters`.

Comment: I think I am definitely lost in here :D.  If I remove the slot tag nothing is changed.

Comment: @Sasha `visible-filters` should be containing the `<slot></slot>` not the `visible-filters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction:

```
<visible-filters>
    <show-query-filter :selected ="true" query="all" name="All | "></show-query-filter>
    <show-query-filter query="true" name="Visible | "></show-query-filter>
    <show-query-filter query="false" name="Hidden"></show-query-filter>
</visible-filters>
```

indicates that the three instances of `show-query-filter` are being used as the contents of a `slot`, but `visible-filters` is not defined with a `slot` in its template.

You *have* defined `show-query-filter` to have a `slot`, but you don't supply any content for it. It isn't clear what your intended result is. Note that slot contents are not children of the component whose slot they are put into.

[Slot scoping rules](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope)